# How can I resize my draw.io diagram in the Confluence data center edition?

Tags: confluence, draw.io

I have created a "Draw.io"-based diagram in our Confluence wiki page.

When I saved the diagram, it looked too small. I tried to increase/resize the diagram using the below guide.

*[Resize the draw.io viewer in Confluence Cloud](https://drawio.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000061101-resize-the-draw-io-viewer-in-confluence-cloud)*

But in our *Data Center version - 7.13.8*, in *Format Panel* I can't see the *Zoom* option.

Isn't this feature supported in our edition?

Answer (score 0):

Please submit all the details, drawio version and print screens to https://drawio.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/14/group/15/create/49

The article you linked is for drawio on Confluence Cloud and you mentioned you are using it on Confluence DC.

Thanks,

Comment: Ok will do that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the viewer in the page to something like 200% and it zoomed the whole plugin.

I also set the drawio zoom in the draw diagram macro.

(I am using embed macro for existing diagrams)